# Solutions of an EDO in tempered distribution space being smooth out of the origin.

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

For $a\in\mathbb{C}$, let us consider the following differential equation in $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$, the set of tempered distributions on $\mathbb{R}$: $$xT''+2T'+(a-x)T=0.$$
For $T\in\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$, $xT''+2T'+(a-x)\in\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$ and since the fourier transform $\mathcal{F}:\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})\to \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$ is an isomorphism, one gets: $$xT''+2T'+(a-x)T=0\Leftrightarrow\widehat{T}'+\frac{ia}{1+\xi^2}\widehat{T}=0.$$
Let $\Delta_a\subseteq\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$ be the set of the solutions of $xT''+2T'+(a-x)T=0$, one derives: $$\dim_{\mathbb{R}}\Delta_a=1.$$
I am asked to proof that:

> $T\in\Delta_a$ is $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^*)$ and for $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $|x|^kT(x)\underset{{|x|\to +\infty}}{\longrightarrow}0$.

At that moment, I know that: $$\widehat{T}(\xi)=C\exp(-ia\arctan(\xi)).$$
I thought using Paley-Wiener theorem, since I am fairly new to Fourier-analysis, I am a bit distraught. Any help will be appreciated, preferably with some hints.

Comment: I think it is possible to establish the desired properties without using the distributional approach: after all, on $(0,+\infty)$ the equation $T''+\frac 2x T' +\frac{a-x}{x}T=0$ is well-defined, so you can establish the existence of maximal solution, then obtain some estimates on the regularity of the solutions and on their decay.

Comment: And as a second thought, where does this problem come from? What does this equation represent?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This equation comes from an exercises sheet of distributions theory and PDE. I notice that for all $k\in\mathbb{N}_{\geqslant 1},\widehat{T}^{(k)}\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, that might help.

Comment: Actually, you can do even better: you know that $\hat T^{(k)}\in L^2(\Bbb R)$ for $k\ge 1$, hence $|x|^kT(x)\in L^2(\Bbb R)$.